# Can't get mod_rewrite to correctly (and invisibly) re-write my URLs?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, short-url

I'm trying to make a URL shortening service for my website.

So instead of:

```
http://www.myfullwebsitename.com/page78/this-is-a-headline/
```

users will be able to visit:

```
http://abc.de/aBxf
```

which needs to redirect (invisibly!) to

```
http://abc.de/?shorturl=aBxf
```

which then 301 redirects via a database lookup to

```
http://www.myfullwebsitename.com/page78/this-is-a-headline/
```

I can do the DB lookup and the 301 redirect easily.  It's the invisible intermediate redirect that I'm struggling with.

I've tried a LOT of different things, but none seems to work.  This is what I currently feel *should* work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc.de
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/(.+)  /?shorturl=$1
```

But instead of redirecting silently to

```
http://abc.de/?shorturl=aBxF
```

it redirects "noisily" (302) to

```
http://abc.de/aBxF/?shorturl=aBxF
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things you can try.

I think your RewriteRule should look like this (without the forward `/`):

```
RewriteRule ^/(.+)  ?shorturl=$1 [L]
```

This should at the very least stop it from redirecting to `http://abc.de/aBxF/`.

Your original rule may work if you add:

```
RewriteBase /
```

If it were me my rules would actually look like this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc.de$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .  /redirect.php [L]
```

And then in PHP I would use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get the URL (not sure what language you're using).

The rule can look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /redirect.php?shorturl=$1 [L]
```

But I would make sure to mention the script by name. Part of what may be throwing your rules off is relying on Apache finding your index file after a rewrite.

The way Apache's rewrite rules work is as soon as the URL is rewritten, it actually will re-run the rules until no other rules will be found. The `[L]` flag for "last" says "stop here" - but it still starts over from the top. The RewriteCond with the `!-f` flag says "only if the file doesn't exist".

Comment: Your rules don't seem to pass anything through to redirect.php, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: You don't have to - if it's an internal redirect you can pick up the original url in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Comment: "But I would make sure to mention the script by name." - THAT was the problem.  Add index.php in and suddenly everything's A-ok.  Thankyou for your help Luke.

Answer (score 0):

Use an absolute URL:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc.de
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://abc.de/?shorturl=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I don't want a 302 *or* a 301.  I should be able to rewrite this URL without the extra HTTP hop that a 302/301 entails - the browser/user doesn't need to know about this intermediate step.

Comment: Ok, I was not really understanding because you were mixing the 301 and 302 codes with the "visible/invisible" part which neither are. I can understand the question but the writing is confusing. See my edit.

Comment: He doesn't want a hard redirect, he wants it to be internal, which is what it isn't doing. The hard redirect is happening in his script (which I assume is written in PHP).

Comment: This one should be internal, shouldn't it? I have several similar rewrites on some applications (for url "prettifying") and the "querystring-version" of the URL never shows in the browser.

Comment: Yeah, it should be, JCL.  I don't understand what's going wrong.  Is it due to the HTTP_HOST RewriteCond that my other redirects don't have?  Maybe that's confusing Apache into thinking that I'm directing from one domain to the other, which obviously isn't possible without a 301/302.  Even though I'm not.

Comment: Was due to me not specifying index.php in the rewrite.  See comments above on Luke's answer.